# Failable Initializers with Codable

Tags: swift, codable

I'm attempting to parse the following json schema of array of items, itemID may not be empty. How do I make an item nil id `itemID` does not exist in the JSON?

```
[{
    "itemID": "123",
    "itemTitle": "Hello"
  },
  {},
  ...
]
```

My decodable classes are as follows:

```
public struct Item: : NSObject, Codable {
    let itemID: String
    let itemTitle: String?
}

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case itemID
    case itemTitle
}

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        itemID = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .itemID)
        itemTitle = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .itemTitle)

        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try declaring it `Optional` as `let itemID: String?`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `itemID` is an `Int` and not `String` in your *`JSON` response*. So the `struct Item` looks like,

```
public struct Item: Codable {
    let itemID: Int?
    let itemTitle: String?
}
```

Parse the `JSON` like,

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let items = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data).filter({$0.itemID == nil})
        print(items)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

In the above code you can simply `filter` out the items with `itemID == nil`.

Comment: I was looking for an approach to return nil from the init of the Item when itemID is nil.

Comment: Failable initializer for Decodable doesn’t exist for now.